# Page jumps up when clicking on hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am building a template which can be seen here: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/aldemair-productions/

when you scroll down and you click on the hamburger menu to open the off-canvas menu (foundation 6) the page jumps up.

This is my js so faR:

```
$(document).foundation();

$(document).ready(function(){
    function carouselInit() {
        if($('.single-project').length > 4 && !$('.slick-initialized').length) {
            $('.single-item').slick({
                responsive: [
                    {
                      breakpoint: 1024,
                      settings: 'unslick'
                    }]
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('4');
        }
    }

    $('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
        if($('header').hasClass('fixed')){
            $('header').removeClass('fixed').addClass('absolute');
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        }
        else {
            $('header').removeClass('absolute').addClass('fixed');
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        }
    });

    carouselInit();

    var resizeId;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(resizeId);
        resizeId = setTimeout(carouselInit, 500);
    });

});
```

When clicking on the hamburger icon the all page shouldn't jump up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the piece of code that makes the page jump:

```
 // Elements with [data-toggle] will toggle a plugin that supports it when clicked.
  $(document).on('click.zf.trigger', '[data-toggle]', function () {
    triggers($(this), 'toggle');
  });
```

When you click on the hamburger menu it triggers 'toggle.zf.trigger' on the element with id 'sth'. This further goes into the open function that has this piece of code:

```
if (this.options.forceTop) {
     $('body').scrollTop(0);
 }
```

Guess what it does? :) I can only assume that setting OffCanvas forceTop option to false will remove this behaviour.